# Error update Android Studio 3 on Mac (Re-download dependencies and sync project requires network)

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded to version 3 and it appeared
Now I do not do anything
I've even cleaned it up again
It did not work right now

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try doing exactly what the error message says?

Comment: Despite the Internet connection
When I download the link again
 Nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday, I was clicking in re-download and it was happening nothing. I just uninstall and deleted all the previous settings from Android Studio 2.2 Then I donwloaded Android Studio 3.0 again without using the settings from the previous versions, updated some things that they asked for me and it worked.